# Locating an element on appium when resource_ids are not available

Tags: xpath, appium

I am trying to create a dynamic XPath for the "Accept" button. But as seen in the screenshot, the button does not have any resource_id, or name in the properties, so I am unable to create a working XPath for the element.

Some of my failed attempts are as follows:

```
xpath=//class[contains(text() = 'ACCEPT')]

xpath=//*[contains(@class, 'ACCEPT')]

xpath=//*[contains(text() = 'ACCEPT')]
```

But whatever I try, the script fails to locate the button. I do not want to use the static XPath that is visible in the screenshot. Is there any way I can make a dynamic XPath for this element?

[image: Properties of the Accept Button]

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
//*[@class="android.widget.Button"][.="ACCEPT"]
```

Safer version :

```
//*[contains(@class,"android.widget.Button")][contains(.,"ACCEPT")]
```

Notes :

```
//class[contains(text() = 'ACCEPT')] : incorrect. You don't look for a class element.
//*[contains(@class, 'ACCEPT')] : incorrect. Class attribute doesn't contain "ACCEPT".
//*[contains(text() = 'ACCEPT')] : correct.
```